# Getting debug output in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm generating a large script to do a bunch of inserts and updates. When I run it I get some errors, but the error messages don't let me pinpoint the problem - the line numbers are since the last "GO", so I can't find the right line.

I'd like to add calls to my script to a function in T-SQL that will just write to the results window, so I'd have a better idea where the error occurs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use [PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) in the pleces that you suspect can cause problems

e.g.

```
print 'Step 1'
insert into tableA -- some code here
...
print 'Step 2'
etc
```

You can also wrap your code into block of [TRY CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) statements and throw custom errors or print error messages if something goes wrong

Answer (score 2):

PRINT statements as suggested by @kristof would do what you want.

However you could run SQL Profiler side-by-side when you execute the script, catching all classes in the `Errors and Warnings` section and all `SQL:StmtStarting` events -- this would mean you wouldn't have to edit your script.